# Adding foreign key - Error Code 1064

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to add a foreign key to my table by the following code:

```
ALTER TABLE scenes ADD CONSTRAINT fk_dancer_charachter FOREIGN KEY (dancer_pick) references characters(character);
```

But it keeps saying: Error Code 1064: You have an error in your sql syntax: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL sever version for the right syntax to use near 'charachter)' at line 1.

Why is that? The syntax seems correct! Isn't it? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `charachter` ? misspeled? isn't this your error?

Comment: i mean : `charachter ` is not the same as `character `

Comment: Yes it was a spelling problem, but now it says: "Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint" any reason?

Comment: Take a look at the post below, if it does not work post the sql script to create the two table you are trying to link with this key

Comment: I spelled it as "Charachter" which is not a reserved word!

Comment: then post the sql script so we can test in : http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Did I insert the create table scripts correctly?

Comment: There is only one table, we need both for trying to create a foreign key ^^

Answer (score 1):

You are using a reserved word - CHARACTER.

More information in [Reserved Words in MySQL 5.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html)